# Vue 2 - Emit event from components with paramethers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to emit event from my component with corresponding parameters, but I can't find a way to send the parameters.

Here is the code so far:

HTML:

```
<td class="countries-visible-filter">
    <visible-filter v-on:countryTest="'all'">All | </visible-filter>
    <visible-filter v-on:countryTest="1">Visible | </visible-filter>
    <visible-filter v-on:countryTest="0">Hidden</visible-filter>
</td>
```

Vue code:

```
Vue.component('visible-filter', {
    template: `
        <span class="text-muted"
            @mouseenter="changeClassMouseenter($event)"
            @mouseout="changeClassMouseout($event)"
            @click="countryTest(param)"
        ><slot></slot></span>
    `,

    methods: {

        changeClassMouseenter(event) {
            event.target.classList.remove('text-muted')
        },

        changeClassMouseout(event) {
            event.target.classList.add('text-muted')
        },

        countryTest(param) {
            Event.$emit('countryFilter', param);
        }
    }

});
```

I am catching the event, but I am not getting entered params. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're actually catching the event? Did you mean you are emitting it? Your event handlers are setting the handlers to strings. Also you typically cannot use camelCased events in a template.

Comment: put a debugger into the `countryTest` method, what value does `param` contain?

Comment: @BertEvans - event is fired, but nothing is passed (I can still catch the event target).

Comment: @phoet - I get **undefined** for a param.

Comment: so where should `param` come from and why do you expect it to be something else?